# How to update SQL Server table rows in different servers using latest technology

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I need to update daily sales & stock details to my head quarter database every EOD, which was located in different server. How can I achieve it by any latest & efficient technique? My application is a .NET 4.0 web application.

Note: existing technique we follow is manual download/upload concept, hitting HQ database and inserting the data and fetching data from HQ database.

Please advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link another server like this

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'S1', 
   @srvproduct=N'',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc=N'192.168.0.1\SQLEXPRESS';
```

then you can use tables from this server like

```
SELECT * FROM S1.Data_1314.dbo.dev_vr_Details;
INSERT INTO dev_vr_Details SELECT * FROM S1.Data_1314.dbo.dev_vr_Details;
```

when you finish your work just remove like like

```
sp_dropserver 'S1', 'droplogins';
```

Comment: Is this the latest technique used, how this technique is efficient where can we collect the exception..?